# question about continuity of a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a function defined as follows:

$$ f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & : x \in \mathbb{Q}\\
       e^x & : x \notin \mathbb{Q}
     \end{array}
   \right. $$

My teacher says that $f$ is only continuous at $0$. I have really hard time trying to show this with a delta-epsilon argument. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to chose a $\delta>0$ given an $\varepsilon>0$ with the usual definitions, you can choose the same $\delta$ (at $x=0$) as for $f(x)=e^x$, since $|1-1|=0$ doesn't impose any restriction (for the choice of $\delta$) if $x\in\mathbb Q$.

Regarding the choice of $\delta$ for $f$, know that $f'(x) = e^x, f'(0) = 1$ so you can chose $\delta \sim \varepsilon$ to achieve
$$|x| < \delta \Rightarrow |e^{x}-1| < \varepsilon$$
For example $\delta = \min(1, \frac\varepsilon{e-1})$ should work if we look at the [plot of $|f(x)-1|$ vs. $\varepsilon(\delta)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=|pow%28e%2Cx%29-1|+%3C+%28e-1%29|x|).

Answer (score 1):

We see that $f(0)=1$ and no matter if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ or $x\notin \mathbb{Q}$ 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}1=1$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}e^x=1$$
However $e^x=1$ for only value $x=0$ and there exists a rational number between each irrational and vice versa. Because of this, the function is not continuous if $x\neq 0$.